# WebApplications, how to notify users when their device is sleeping

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, push-notification, notifications

I've build a Javascript WebApp that is designed to work on tablets (using Web App Manifest file) and offline (aside from getting initial data from PHP backend). The app has custom notification system imitating Notifications API. Each notification is sent at given time (using `setInterval`). This leads to couple of problems:

- there is no sound as the notifications are not effect of user interaction,
- notifications can't be shown when the device is asleep.

First problem can be solved using Notifications API, but I'm not sure what could be done about the second. Keep in mind that the app should work offline - this eliminates the use of Push Notifications API.

Is using web application's container such as Cordova my only option?

Comment: I certainly will throw my tablet to a wall if it will notify me when it is __sleeping__ ... That would be more like a virus, not a useful feature.

Comment: @Teemu The app has a special use case and therefore it is vital for users that they're notified.